# Proof using prime factorization and fundamental theorem of arithmetic

Tags: proof-writing, prime-numbers, proof-explanation, prime-factorization

> Let $x$ and $y$ be positive integers such that $7x^5 = 11y^{13}$. The minimum value of $x$ can be written in the form $a^cb^d$, where $a, b, c, d$ are positive integers. Compute $a + b + c + d$.

What is a good way to go about solving this proof? What would an exhaustive proof of this look like?

Comment: (Hint) Can $x$ have a factor of $11$? Can $y$ have a factor of $7$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Observe $x$ must have at least one factor of $11$ since $11$ is prime and $11\mid 7x^5 \implies 11\mid 7 \text{ or } 11\mid x^5$. A similar argument shows that $7$ must be a prime factor of $y$ and thus a prime factor of $x$. Since $x$ is minimal, it must have only two prime factors and $x = 7^c11^d$. Similarly, $y$ is of the form $y = 7^{c'}11^{d'}$. Since two integers are equal if there prime factorizations are equal, it follows that 
\begin{align}
5c+1&=13c'\\
5d &= 13d'+1
\end{align}
Our problem has been reduced to a system of equations where $c,c',d,d'$ are positive whole numbers. A quick inspection yields the solution
\begin{align}
c &= 5 \\ c' &= 2 \\ d &=8 \\ d' &= 3
\end{align}
Hence, $x = 7^5\cdot11^8$ and $a+b+c+d = 31$.

Comment: This makes perfect sense. Thanks for the clear explanation!